# UIAccess with Drag and Drop

Tags: c++, wpf, winapi

There are several questions about drag and drop not working when `UIAccess` is enabled. Some offer a partial solution of using `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` or `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx` with `WM_DROPFILES`. However, this does not work for `wpf` applications.

Any ideas?

Comment: Self answering your question is fine, but it must still come in Q&A format to fit well here. Please move your solution to an answer.

Comment: I just upvoted your question so you now have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) points to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a `UIAccess` enabled app is launched with `High Integrity` - this is what prevents Drag and Drop from working.

I tried changing the integrity level to medium from within the app itself but that did not have any effect.

For others looking for a solution, this is what I came up with. From another `UIAccess` enabled process you can launch your process using `CreateProcessAsUser` .... below is the code

```
HANDLE hToken;
HANDLE hTokenDup;
DWORD dwUIAccess = 1;

OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken);
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hTokenDup);

// enable UIAccess
SetTokenInformation(hTokenDup, TokenUIAccess, &dwUIAccess, sizeof(dwUIAccess));

// medium integrity sig
ConvertStringSidToSid(L"S-1-16-8192", &pSid);

TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = { 0 };

tml.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY;
tml.Label.Sid = pSid;

// set medium integrity
SetTokenInformation(hTokenDup, TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, sizeof(tml) + GetLengthSid(pSid));

FreeSid(pSid);

CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDup, pathToExe, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)
```

Hope this helps ...